# Chamar uma página wordpress em página PHP

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, paginação, http-headers

Tentei utilizar o seguinte comando para ir a uma página wordpress, porém não funcionou.

```
echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;URL=$buscahttp>';
<script>location.href = 'http://www.xxx/¨'.$buscahttp</script>');

header('Location: '.$buscahttp);
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Use só a função `header()`.

Comment: A PAGINA CHAMADA É DINÂMICA OU VARIÁVEL, COM ENDERÇO FIXO FUNCIONA.

Comment: O que não funciona exatamente, ele vai pra uma página invalida? Me parece um erro na variavel `$buscahttp` e não no redirecionamento. De mais detalhes.

Answer (score 4):

Aparentemente você está misturando o PHP com Javascript ai.

Para fazer esse redirecionamento (me corrija se estiver errado) você pode fazer o seguinte:

Utilizando **PHP**: (lembrando que para funcionar deve ser feita antes de qualquer saída html que o php possa executar)

```
$redirect = 'http://suaurl.com.br';
header("location:$redirect");
```

Utilizando **Javascript**:

```
<script>
  location.href = 'http://uol.com.br';
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos foi resolvido mas tive que colocar o comando ob_start();.